# TEXT BASED GAME: I'm having trouble getting my code to run. I keep getting an issue with my starting location at the "West Gate Entrance"

Tags: python

```
rooms = {
    "West Gate Entrance": {"East": "Great Hall"},
    "Great Hall": {
        "North": "library",
        "South": "Solar",
        "East": "Kitchen",
        "West": "Start",
    },
    "library": {"East": "Bed Chambers", "South": "Great Hall"},
    "Bed Chambers": {"West": "Library"},
    "Kitchen": {"West": "Great Hall", "North": "Lost Room"},
    "Lost Room": {"South": "Kitchen"},
    "Solar": {"North": "Great Hall", "East": "East Tower"},
}

items = {
    "Great Hall": "Castle Map",
    "Library": "Sword",
    "Bed Chambers": "Lost Key",
    "Lost Room": "Heart Container",
    "Kitchen": "Potion",
    "Solar": "Shield",
    "East Tower": "Ghost Knight",
}

state = "West Gate Entrance"
inventory = []


# function
def get_new_state(state, direction):
    new_state = state  # declaring
    for i in rooms:  # loop
        if i == state:  # if
            if direction in rooms[i]:  # if
                new_state = rooms[i][direction]  # assigning new_state

    return new_state  # return


while 1:  # gameplay loop
    print("You are now in the ", state)  # printing state
    if state == "East Tower":
        print("You have entered battle with the Ghost Knight!", end="")
        for i in range(50):
            for j in range(1000000):
                pass
            print(".", end="", flush=True)
        print()
        if len(inventory) == 6:
            print(
                "Congratulations! You have located all 6 items and slain the Ghost Knight"
            )
        else:
            print("You have succumbed to your wounds...GAME OVER!")
        break

    print("In this room you see a", items[state])
    print("You now have", inventory)
    direction = input(
        "Enter item you want OR direction to go OR exit to give up: "
    )  # asking user
    if direction.lower() == items[state].lower():
        if items[state] not in inventory:
            inventory.append(items[state])
        continue
    direction = direction.capitalize()  # making first character capital remaining lower
    if direction == "Exit":  # if
        exit(0)  # exit function
    if (
        direction == "East"
        or direction == "West"
        or direction == "North"
        or direction == "South"
    ):  # if
        new_state = get_new_state(state, direction)  # calling function
        if new_state == state:  # if
            print("There is no move in that direction direction!")  # print
        else:
            state = new_state  # changing state value to new_state
    else:
        print("Please input a valid direction!")  # print
```

I'm trying to make a starting room where the player will start the game however I keep getting a `KeyError` at the `"West Gate Entrance'`.

Comment: The [tag:pygame] tag is only for questions about the [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news) API, but not in general fro questions about games written with Python.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you haven't defined any items in `West Gate Entrance`. Make the following changes:

```
print("In this room you see a", items.get(state, "nothing"))
```

and

```
if state in items and direction.lower() == items[state].lower():
    if items[state] not in inventory:
        inventory.append(items[state])
```

so that you print a default value (`"nothing"`) when there are no items in a room.

Answer (score -1):

you should edit the "items" its missing one state("West Gate Entrance").

```
items = {
"Great Hall": "Castle Map",
"Library": "Sword",
"Bed Chambers": "Lost Key",
"Lost Room": "Heart Container",
"Kitchen": "Potion",
"Solar": "Shield",
"East Tower": "Ghost Knight",
}
```

to

```
items = {
"Great Hall": "Castle Map",
"Library": "Sword",
"Bed Chambers": "Lost Key",
"Lost Room": "Heart Container",
"Kitchen": "Potion",
"Solar": "Shield",
"East Tower": "Ghost Knight",
"West Gate Entrance" : ""
}
```